# How to Resolve 403 error during API call through eks cluster by CURL

Tags: api, kubernetes, curl, amazon-eks

I am trying to access my eks cluster through API . While calling by curl i am getting this error .
{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {

},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "db1 is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "db1" in API group "" in the namespace "default"",
"reason": "Forbidden",
"details": {
"kind": "db1"
},
"code": 403

Can anybody help me how to resolve this error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forbidden response comes in case of access violation. The curl request you made is not having any authorization involved in it. Further AWS EKS has it's own User access list that can be found with

```
kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth
```

You need to assume one of the role allowed in the above configmap then you can generate the access token needed with

```
aws sts get-session-token
```

Using this token you will be able to access your eks cluster over curl

Comment: {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 404                                                                                                                                    well i am getting this 401 now ... also tried to get the session token but could not able to get since its giving error like --> Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials

Comment: @JuniperDevops use this command  aws eks get-token --cluster-name <cluster-name> along with you aws-iam-aunthenticator installed